# docker で http アクセスを記録するだけのコンテナ

Tags: docker, http

docker で構築した開発環境で複数のサーバー間の結合テストを行うとき
あるサーバーから別のサーバーへのリクエストの内容をみたいことが多いのですが

受け取るサーバー側のコードにデバッグログを仕込んでいて
デバッグをつけたりコメントアウトしたりコードがどんどん汚くなるので
単にHTTPのリクエスト内容を保存するようなサーバーを立てて
docker-compose の接続先の名前だけ切り替えてデバッグできるといいなと思ってます

HTTP のエコーサーバーに関しては記事があるのですが
HTTP サーバーを立てて
resuponsuha 200OK 固定とかでいいので
飛んでくる GET や POST の中身を保存するようなコンテナを簡単に作れるような
テンプレートコンテナみたいなのはあったりしないでしょうかは作れないでしょうか

nginx や apache を立てただけだと ヘッダの情報や POST BODY がわからないし
エコーサーバーを使うと結局送信側でレスポンス内容を記録しなければいけないので解決にならないので
サーバー側で記録までしたいです

コンテナ自体に完備されてなくても汎用的な Linux コンテナの bash 上で
ワンラインやごく簡単に書けるような http サーバーを動かす方法とかでも構わないです

いい実現方法があれば教えていただけるとありがたいです

Answer (score 1):

Apache httpd の [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dumpio.html) を使うといいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 入れてみたんですがログの大半が不要な情報で膨大な量になってしまいます。必要なヘッダとPOST BODYだけなのである程度ログの中身をカスタマイズできるものだとありがたいです