# mod_security の設定方法

Tags: docker, apache, http

[docker で http アクセスを記録するだけのコンテナ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70686/docker-%e3%81%a7-http-%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%82%92%e8%a8%98%e9%8c%b2%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%86%e3%83%8a)

こちらの質問で mod_dumpio を教えていただいたんですが
ログの中身が不要な情報が多すぎてみにくい上にカスタマイズ方法もわからないので

https://cloudpack.media/31715
こちらを参考にして mod_security というのを入れようと思っています

Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-security2

COPY ./modsecurity.conf /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
```

とだけ書いて modsecurity.conf の中身はとりあえずブログと同じものにしました

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecRequestBodyAccess On
 
SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/post-request.log
SecAuditLogParts ABCFHZ
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "POST" "id:100000,phase:2,nolog,pass"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "^\/memo/write$" "id:100001,ctl:auditEngine=On"
```

コンテナに対してブログと同じ curl を叩いてみると当然 htdocs が空なので 404 になるんですが
apache 自体は応答しています

```
# curl localhost/memo/wirte -d 'test'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

ただ肝心のログファイル /var/log/apache2/post-request.log には何も出力されません

そもそも httpd コンテナの場合 apache が /usr/local/apache2 に入っていて
apt-get install だけで mod_security 関連の変更が加わってる様子がありません
このモジュールを有効にするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか
.so ファイルをどこかにおいて Load Module を書かないといけない気がするんですが
apt-get でどこに何が配置されたのかがわかりません

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#Installation_for_Apache
公式のドキュメントには apt-get によるインストール方法ではなくソースからビルドする方法しか乗ってないんですが docker 上に入れたいのであまり gcc とかビルドライブラリを入れてイメージを大きくしたくないです

---

前の質問と重複するんですがやりたいことは HTTP リクエストを受け取ってヘッダと POST BODY をログに残すだけの docker コンテナを作リたいのですがもっと簡単に実現する方法ってないんでしょうか…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpd コンテナは debian 10 ベースですが、/usr/local/apache2 にインストールされている /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd (2.4.46) は apt 管理ではなく、独自にインストールしたもののようです。

apt の mod_security を使うのであれば、apt install apache2 でインストールされる /usr/sbin/apache2 (2.4.38) を使う必要があります。

Comment: httpd もべつにいれないといけないなら httpd コンテナを使うメリットがないのでOSだけ入ってるコンテナに RUN yum install -y httpd mod_security だけで動かせました！　デフォルトで結構複雑な設定ファイルがあったんですがブログを参考にPOST BODYだけ出力するシンプルなものに置き換えてやりたいことができました！　ありがとうございます